# How to return to Fragment from Activity on Back Press

Tags: android, button, android-activity, fragment, back

In Android Studio I created a HomeFragment from MainActivity, then a new Activity is started when Bluetooth Data arrives. When I press the Back button while in the new Activity, the app closes. I want the App to go back to the HomeFragment.

I tried the following in the new Activity: But the App still closes

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
```

Here is the flow of my code for the sequence mentioned.

[image]

Comment: Sorry first block is : Service_BTLE_GATT.MainActivity.

Comment: And when starting Activity_ListViewInp,  context = Service_BTLE_GATT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch `Activity_ListViewInp` you have added `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`. This will remove all existing activities from the task and start a new instance of `Activity_ListViewInp`. When you then press BACK, the app exits because there are no other activities in the task.

Remove `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`